# React js - react router on shared server - Ionos-

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a problem uploading my react js application to a shared server. When reloading a page other than the index, it marks "Internal Server Error".
but browsing the menu opens them correctly.
in the same way, if I want to enter directly, it marks an error.

example.

food / -> Correct.

food / plate -> Correct

but if I relapse this last mark error.

in my package.json I have:

"homepage": ".",

and the routes I declare this way.

```
<Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={View_Inicio} />
          <Route path="/Nosotros" component={View_Nosotros} />
          <Route path="/Platillos" exact component={View_Platillos} />
          <Route path="/Platillos/:id" component={View_Platillos_Detalle} />
          <Route path="/Promosiones" component={View_Promosiones} />
          <Route path="/Orden" component={View_Orden} />
         </Switch>
</Router>
```

It is worth mentioning that locally if it works correctly

Comment: I have the same problem with Ionos, Did you finally solve it?